# How to browse source code in developer console on Google Compute Engine

Tags: repository, google-compute-engine

I have used Click to deploy MEAN Stack on Google Compute Engine. Everything is fine, runs in the Cloud and on my local machine.

When I try to browse source code in the developer console, I get the Getting startet screen for cloud source tools.
Should it not be set up automatically when I created the instance?

When I SSH into the instance I can see the content of opt/myApp.
This I would like to see in browse source code also.

If I try to git clone the Cloud Repository it is empty.

I'm currently using the trial version. Maybe this is the reason I can not browse or clone the Cloud Repository?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good suggestion.  It would be very interesting to integrate click to deploy in more Google Cloud Platform services. The MEAN click to deploy doesn't have much of a sample application installed, which is why it doesn't make sense to put it in a code repository.  The application stack itself (mongo, express, angular, node) you wouldn't put in a repository, which is really the only thing installed on the MEAN Click to Deploy server.